# Is it possible to terminate a process from Chrome packaged application onSuspend or onClose?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to debug an packaged app which is based on [Chrome App Sample WebSocket Server](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/websocket-server). First time I'm working with Chrome Apps so be kind.

When I run the app from Google Dev Editor I can open and close the application as I like. However, when installing it from the Chrome App Store, re-opening the app crashes my Chromebook = screen goes black for a few seconds, then comes back with all programs closed.

I'm not really sure where to start debugging this and as my extension is pretty much all copied from the app samples, it may also be a bug. I did find out, that if I terminate the process which remains in the shift+esc task manager by hand, I can restart the app without crashing.

I looked a little into ways to run things on closing of the app. I think I cannot use:

```
chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function() {
  // kill process here
});
```

but maybe:

```
chrome.app.window.onClosed.addListener(function (){
  // kill process here
});
```

would be usable, provided I have access to the processes and know the process id. I did find this [blog post](http://www.bitfalls.com/2013/09/build-chrome-extension-killing-chrome.html) and [gist](https://gist.github.com/Swader/6556262) on the topic, suggesting this would be possibe:

```
var tab_id;
var processes = (chrome.processes !== undefined) ? chrome.processes :   chrome.experimental.processes;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    tab_id = tab.id;
    processes.getProcessIdForTab(tab.id, function (processId) {
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(processId)) && isFinite(processId)) {
            processes.terminate(processId);
        }
    });
});

processes.onExited.addListener(function (id, exitType, exitCode) {
    if (exitType == 2 && exitCode == 15) {
        chrome.tabs.reload(tab_id);
    }
});
```

but I'm not able to access the processes as shown in the code (guess it's too old).

**Question:**
Is it at all possible to access the processes running from a Chrome App to try and terminate a process? If not how best tackle this then?

Thanks!

Comment: Your final question is quit generic. I think that your use case would also be satisfied if you have a way to kill an app from within an app, right?

Comment: @RobW: yes. That would work!

Comment: There are several ways to induce a crash, here is one of them: https://crbug.com/447414